# CSS/Javascript: Mark clicked Shapes with small Rectangles on Corners

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a University Project, I'm currently trying to do a sort of "Selection" - Function for Drawn Shapes like Rectangles, Circles, Lines or Triangles.

The "OnClick"-Event for the respective Shape shouldn't be the problem. But currently I can't figure out, how to handle the visualization of the selection the best way.

If the User is selecting one of the shapes, the corners shall display small rectangles just like in Microsoft Word etc. - the final result shall look something like this:

[image]

But I have no idea, how to change the border or the border-corners of the drawn Shapes to display small rectangles on its ends.

Can you help me out here?

Thank you in Advance!

```js
var draw_area = document.getElementById('draw_area');


function drawRect(){

  var object = draw_area.getContext('2d');
  object.beginPath();
  object.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
  object.stroke();

};

function drawLine(){

  var object = draw_area.getContext('2d');
  object.beginPath();
  object.moveTo(230, 100);
  object.lineTo(330, 100);
  object.stroke();

};

function drawTriangle(){

  var object = draw_area.getContext('2d');
  object.beginPath();
  object.moveTo(420, 50);
  object.lineTo(470, 150);
  object.lineTo(370, 150);
  object.lineTo(420, 50);
  object.stroke();

};

function drawCircle(){

  var object = draw_area.getContext('2d');
  object.beginPath();
  object.arc(600, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  object.stroke(); 

}

drawRect();
drawLine();
drawTriangle();
drawCircle();
```

```css
#draw_area{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="draw_area" height="700", width="700"> </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us how you are handling the click events - I can't see where you are 'remembering' what objects you have on the canvas or where you are putting them or what their dimensions are - info you'll need to place those little squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew the corners for a rectangle:

```js
class Program
{
    constructor(draw_area)
  {
    this.draw_area = draw_area;
    this.ctx = draw_area.getContext('2d');
    this.objects = [];
    
    draw_area.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this), false);
  }
  
  draw()
  {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 700);
    this.objects.forEach((o) => o.draw());
  }
  
  drawRect(x, y, w, h)
  {
    this.objects.push(new Rectangle(this.ctx, x, y, w, h));
  }
    
  handleClick(event)
  {
    var x = event.pageX - this.draw_area.offsetLeft + this.draw_area.clientLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - this.draw_area.offsetTop + this.draw_area.clientTop;

    this.objects.forEach((o) => 
    {
        if (y > o.y && y < o.y + o.h && x > o.x && x < o.x + o.w) 
        {
            o.selected = !o.selected;
        }
    });
    
    this.draw();
  }
}

class Rectangle
{
    constructor(ctx, x, y, w, h)
  {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.cornerSize = 10;
    this.selected = false;
  }
  
  draw()
  {
    
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.stroke();
    
    if(!this.selected)
        return;
    
    this.ctx.beginPath();

    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";


        
    // Corner rects
    this.ctx.rect(
      this.x - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.y - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.cornerSize, 
      this.cornerSize
    );

    this.ctx.rect(
      this.x + this.w - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.y - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.cornerSize, 
      this.cornerSize
    );

    this.ctx.rect(
      this.x + this.w - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.y + this.h - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.cornerSize, 
      this.cornerSize
    );

    this.ctx.rect(
      this.x - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.y + this.h - this.cornerSize / 2,
      this.cornerSize, 
      this.cornerSize
    );

    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}

var draw_area = document.getElementById('draw_area');
let program = new Program(draw_area);

program.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
program.drawRect(200, 50, 100, 100);
program.draw();
```

```css
#draw_area{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="draw_area" height="700", width="700"> </canvas>
</div>
```

If we look at the drawRect function:

```
function drawRect(x, y, w, h){
    const cornerSize = 10;
  var object = draw_area.getContext('2d');
  object.beginPath();
  object.rect(x, y, w, h);
  object.closePath();

  object.stroke();
  object.beginPath();
  
  object.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  object.strokeStyle = "#000000";

  
  // Corner rects
  object.rect(
    x - cornerSize / 2,
    y - cornerSize / 2,
    cornerSize, 
    cornerSize
  );
  
  object.rect(
    x + w - cornerSize / 2,
    y - cornerSize / 2,
    cornerSize, 
    cornerSize
  );
  
  object.rect(
    x + w - cornerSize / 2,
    y + h - cornerSize / 2,
    cornerSize, 
    cornerSize
  );
  
  object.rect(
    x - cornerSize / 2,
    y + h - cornerSize / 2,
    cornerSize, 
    cornerSize
  );
  
  object.closePath();
  object.fill();
  object.stroke();

};
```

These lines are for first drawing the main rectangle:

```
object.beginPath();
object.rect(x, y, w, h);
object.closePath();    
object.stroke();
```

It is important to call the closePath here, so that the canvas understands that this rectangle is a separate thing from the corner rectangles.

Then we just do a few calculations and draw the corner rectangles in correct positions like so:

```
// top-left corner
object.rect(
    x - cornerSize / 2,
    y - cornerSize / 2,
    cornerSize, 
    cornerSize
);
```

We use `closePath` and `fill` in the end to apply the coloring rules at the top:

```
object.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
object.strokeStyle = "#000000";
```

Note that since you are doing this with pure canvas and not using any canvas library like Fabric.js for example, you are going to have to do everything manually. Though even with a library, you will probably have to manually calculate the small rectangle positions for each shape anyway.

Comment: Wow - thank you very much! So I really need to draw every small rectangle of the selected Shape by itself? There's no "border-corner" -Option in CSS or inside Javascript to simply add custom corners?

Comment: How are the corners going to be drawn (and undrawn) on a click without somehow remembering what objects have been drawn?

Comment: @Cptain_Whitebeard Not really no. Some library might have thought of that if you're lucky. The Canvas API only supplies you with the very basic tools for drawing stuff on the canvas, everything else has to be built on top of that one way or another. Think of it like a pen store - it's only job is to supply you with pen and paper, the drawing is on you and the pen store couldn't possibly accomodate for every client and situation, but with the pens they sell, the clients are enabled to do whatever they need.

Comment: @AHaworth The post said that the clicking and selecting part is out of scope here, so I didn't care for that. You'd have to do a bunch of changes to implement selection.

Comment: @AHaworth I implemented a simple "selection" for fun: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/u1bqh90v/22/

Comment: @Swiffy Understood - It was more a message for the OP than for you as you'd answered what was asked!